# Export Maps for GPS navigators?

Tags: google-maps, gps, maps, gis, openstreetmap

What is the concept behind exporting maps to GPS navigators from a Google Map or Open Street Map? Is there such a thing in the first place? Is there a standardized GPS format which will allow the exporting/importing of coordinates to all the GPS navigators?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPX (called gps exchange) is a common format created (i think) by Garmin. Not all programs (ArcGIS) use it but it can be handily converted to a kml/kmz (keyhole aka Google Earth), and vice-versa. I have found that moving geodatabases between GIS editors, GPS navigators, and GPS handheld units to be most easily accomplished using a program that converts gpx to kml.

tl;dr There is no one format. There are two easily interchangeable formats, GPX and KML.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized GPS format for different GPS manufacturers, most of those formats are proprietary and closed since this suits their business model (selling maps for their units). If you're interested how things stand in OSM world, you can take a look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Map_On_Garmin